# Уменьшительно-ласкательный суффикс

Tags: суффиксы, морфология

Уменьшительно-ласкательный суффикс — это формообразующий?

Например, *миленький* — суффикс **-еньк-**, или *ножка* — суффикс **-к-**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, словообразующие, смысловые

Формообразующие:

1) инфинитив -ть / -ти:

2) прош. время изъяв. наклонения  -л— (дела-л— ) и -Ø-: нёс-Ø— — ср.: нес-л-а.

3)  в условном наклонении: дела-л-Ø бы, нёс-Ø— бы.

4) повелительное наклонение  —и- (пиш-и— ) и -Ø— (делай-Ø-¤, сядь-Ø-¤).

5) причастие  -ащ-(-ящ-), -ущ-(-ющ-), -ш-, -вш-, -им-, -ом— / -ем-, -нн-, -онн— / -енн-, -т-: бег-ущ-ий, взя-т-ый .

6) деепричастие -а(-я), -в, -ши, -вши, -учи(-ючи): делаj-я, буд-учи.

7) простая сравнительная степень прилагательного и наречия -е (выш-е), -её / -ей (быстр-ее), -ше (рань-ше), -же (глуб-же);

8) простая превосходная степень сравнения прилагательного образуется с помощью формообразовательный суффиксов -ейш— / -айш— (быстр-ейш-ий, высоч-айш-ий).